# PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to retrieve a document from the Azure Cosmos Db Collection. I am running into an error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.] with root cause
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
```

I was trying to look up online how can I provide the partition key value to the function findById(), but it seems like the "Azure Spring data cosmosdb" doesn't have the option to provide the partition key with the function for the java implementation

```
orderTransactionRepository.findById("id").get
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searched for the [test code](https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/data/cosmosdb/repository/integration/AddressRepositoryIT.java#L71) of findById method for partitioned collection which is mentioned in the home page of [spring-data-cosmos](http://To%20specify%20a%20field%20of%20domain%20class%20to%20be%20partition%20key%20field,%20just%20annotate%20it%20with%20@PartitionKey.%20When%20you%20do%20CRUD%20operation,%20pls%20specify%20your%20partition%20value.%20For%20more%20sample%20on%20partition%20CRUD,%20pls%20refer%20to%20test%20here).

```
@Test
    public void testFindByIdForPartitionedCollection() {
        final List<Address> addresses = repository.findByPostalCode(TestConstants.POSTAL_CODE);

        assertThat(addresses.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode().equals(TestConstants.POSTAL_CODE));
        assertThat(addresses.get(1).getPostalCode().equals(TestConstants.POSTAL_CODE));
    }
```

You could find the statements [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/blob/268fef9c0520fb8cb10c38d115a91ec6984cbbe8/QueryPartitionedCollection.md):

For Partitioned collection, if you want to query records by findById(id), exception will be thrown.

```
// Incorrect for partitioned collection, exception will be thrown
   Address result = repository.findById(id);  // Caution: Works for non-partitioned collection
```

Instead, you can query records by ID field name with custom query.

```
// Correct, postalCode is the ID field in Address domain
   @Repository
   public interface AddressRepository extends DocumentDbRepository<Address, String> {
      List<Address> findByPostalCode(String postalCode);
   }

   // Query
   List<Address> result = repository.findByPostalCode(postalCode);
```

Another way i found that you could still could use Document DB normal sdk in the spring-data-cosmos package,you just need to encapsulate the method in a simple way. Please refer to this [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/blob/76cc6f61342995c1f431967b36df10027b7a7b13/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/data/cosmosdb/performance/service/SdkService.java#L74).

---

Just for summarized , it was basically due to Spring data commons changing the interface name that the querylookupstrategy was implementing. You need go back to the previous version of the `cosmos-db i.e. 2.0.5`! Here is the link stating the issue github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/304

Comment: I tried with custom query but again ran into an error "Custom query method must have a strategy". I tried creating a query using @Query annotation but that works for Jpa Repository and not DocumentDb. Can you tell which annotation would solve the purpose?

Comment: I figures out the error, it was basically due to Spring data commons changing the interface name that the querylookupstrategy was implementing. After going back to the previous version of the cosmos-db i.e. 2.0.5. I was able to resolve the problem!

Here is the link stating the issue https://github.com/Microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/304

Comment: @NikhilJain It's so kind for your sharing,i summarized your solution for others' reference on the forum.Thanks a lot.