# How do I set a Partition Key for CosmosDb in Spring Boot

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

The answer may seem obvious, but I have tried numerous combinations of annotations and configurations and cannot find a way to implement this that works in all cases (such as capacity to do CRUD, DocumentDbRepository, and custom methods).

Annotation example:

```
@Data
@...
@Document(collection="items")
public class Item {
   @Id
   private String itemId;
   @PartitionKey
   private String storeNumber;
   ...
}
```

Configuration example:

```
...
    public DocumentClient config() {
      DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
            uri, key, getConnectionPolicy(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        client.readDatabases(new FeedOptions()).getQueryIterator().forEachRemaining(database -> {
            System.out.println("Spring database link = " + database.getSelfLink());
        });

        /*
        DocumentCollection coll = new DocumentCollection();
        coll.setId("itemId");
// Corrected based on Sajeetharan's answer:
        PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition = new  PartitionKeyDefinition();
        Collection<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        partitionKeyDefinition.setPaths(paths);
        paths.add("storeNumber");
        coll.setPartitionKey(partitionKeyDefinition);
        coll.setResourceId("items");

        // OR

        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        options.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey("clubNumber"));

        try {
            client.createCollection(String.format("/dbs/%s", DATABASE), coll, options);
        } catch (DocumentClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */

        return client;
    }
...
```

So far, my code works when I let Microsoft handle the partition key for me, and just specify an @Id field along with a client config. However, I want to utilize a specific partition key in this case. The above examples are only a small sample of the different combinations I have tried implementing in order to get this to work. Still, I am winding up with exceptions like: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation` for something as simple as a `findById()`. With that said, I would appreciate some help in finding a solution for this.

For the record, each of the three examples given will actually create a collection for me in Spring boot upon deleting the collection in the Azure UI. And in settings, the partition key is shown to be '/storeNumber', the correct partition key that I did not set manually in the Azure UI. This leaves me at a loss as to why the compiler is complaining that I have not supplied a partition key, even though spring boot is directly responsible for the generating a collection with the (correct) partition key that I am seeing in the Azure UI.

I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cosmosdb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency> <!-- mainly needed for @Id -->
```

in my POM.

*** Would appreciate someone to guide me in what I should do now that my question has been resolved. If marking the question as duplicate or taking down the question completely is appropriate I'll gladly do so, but I do feel that this could be useful for someone else. In the meantime, I will answer my own question since the answer given did not resolve it directly, even though the link provided in the comment did help tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my question, everything (CRUD/DocumentDbRepository/Custom methods) worked fine before using the @PartitionKey annotation in order to choose my own partition key, rather than have Microsoft manage it for me. Although saving and deleting continued to work fine, the DocumentDbRespository methods such as `findById(String id)`, etc. were throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` and complaining that a partition key must be supplied. This was initially puzzling because the partion key was supplied in Spring boot, and was registered in the cosmos database generated by Spring boot. The solution was to provide method signatures in the repository that mapped the field names. For example the signature in:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends DocumentDbRepository<Transaction, String> {
   public List<Transaction> findByTxId(String txId);
}
```

worked as expected, whereas this signature:

`public Optional<Transaction> findById(String id)`

would cause the exception to be thrown.

For more information, see the comments in Sajeetharan's answer. Additionally, Jay Gong provides a great explanation in answering Nikhil Jain's question found here: [PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640748/partitionkey-value-must-be-supplied-for-this-operation).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set like this,

```
 PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition = new PartitionKeyDefinition();
 Collection<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
 paths.add(partitionKey);
 partitionKeyDefinition.setPaths(paths);
 collection.setPartitionKey(partitionKeyDefinition);
```

Comment: Yeah you're right about that. Thanks for your response, unfortunately the issues are the same either way.

Comment: what do you mean by issues are the same

Comment: The exception did not change from telling me that a partition key must be supplied. I think that I mistakenly included both my partition key definition and the requestOptions in the col constructor, resulting in the '/storeNumber' partition key appearing in Azure. But even now that the partitionKeyDefinition has been corrected, the end result seems unchanged, at least based on what is appearing in the compiler.

Comment: hmm strange, may be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640748/partitionkey-value-must-be-supplied-for-this-operation

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help @Sajeetharan, solved the problem by referring to that link. It turns out that after I started using @PartitionKey I was unable to use the simple findById() provided directly by the DocumentDbRepository interface. Initially, I tried to write my own ```public Optional<Transaction> getTransactionById(String myId)``` signature, but what I really needed was ```List<Transaction> getTransactionByMyId(String myId)``` (note the field name in the signature, rather than Id).